# How to share TypeScript code correctly between Aurelia CLI projects?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to develop a local Node package written in TypeScript that I can import into multiple Aurelia CLI projects in the same solution.

I've created a sample solution at:

https://github.com/sam-piper/aurelia-library

which demonstrates my progress so far - the tooling mirrors our development infrastructure (VS 2017 / ASP.NET Core / Aurelia CLI / TypeScript).

The shared exports are compiling correctly in the referencing Aurelia project, and **au build** is also working with no reported errors, but the files are not being bundled correctly, resulting in lots of 404 errors for individual script files when the application loads.

Basically, I need help trying to get this final step working. I'm not sure exactly how the shared project should be structured and built so that it will be compatible for both TypeScript compilation AND Aurelia bundling.

Open to any suggestions!

Comment: Why couldn't you get it working using AMD? It transpiled it for me to that with no problems.

Comment: What's more, the app is running fine for me without any 404s. I inspected the app bundle and your shared items are there. This tells me that your basic structure is correct, and we should indeed focus on why you cannot transpile to AMD.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the module format to AMD in the library project and it really is working for me now - it wasn't the first time I tried AMD, but I think that was because I hadn't setup the index file for the package so I wasn't able to consume the types from the application project. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was just to change the module output in tsconfig.json in the Shared.Lib project to "amd", with no other changes (ie, keeping outDir set to "dist" as well).

The index.ts file works correctly to export all types, and the AMD format is bundled correctly by Aurelia for runtime deployment.

I've updated the repository in case anyone wants to use it as a starting point.